# Show message if term slug changed

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, notifications

Is there any way to catch changing specific field in custom taxonomy term? For example, i need to show notice in back-end, when slug in custom taxonomies term is changed. I'm reading about `edited_term` and `wp_update_term_data` but don't understand how to use it in my case.

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: After you push "Update" button on the "Edit Taxonomy" screen the admin notice is shown by default: `Item updated. ← Back to Categories`

Comment: The thing your are speaking is working with all fileds in term. I need special message fo changing slug in term.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no hook to cling when changing just the slug. You have to dope out what exactly was updated (like 'not Name' or 'not Descritpion').